# Invariant distribution of Markov process with discrete time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

We define invariant distribution of (general) Markov process with homogenne time $\left\{X_t\right\}_{t\in T}$ as
$$\forall t\in T, \forall A\in B(S), \hspace{0.2cm} \pi(A)=\int\limits_{S}P(X_t\in A|X_0=x)\pi(dx),$$
where B(S) is Borel $\sigma\text{-algebra}$ defined on state space $S$.

I should show that for invariant distribution $\pi$ of Markov process with discrete time is sufficient
$$ \forall A\in B(S), \hspace{0.2cm} \pi(A)=\int\limits_{S}P(X_1\in A|X_0=x)\pi(dx).$$

I can show this for Markov chains with discrete time from matrix form of invarinat distribution and I also can do it when it is in summation ( $\sum$ ) form, when I have to use Chapman-Kolmogorov equation.

I have been trying to use Chapman-Kolmogorov equation for Markov process with discrete time, but I have not be successful, yet.

Chapman-Kolmogorv equation is
$$\forall t,s\in T,\forall x\in S,\forall A \in B(S): P(X_{s+t}\in A|X_0=x)=\int\limits_{S}P(X_t\in A|X_0=y)P(X_s\in dy|X_0=x).$$

I have been trying to multiply both side of $$\pi(A)=\int\limits_{S}P(X_1\in A|X_0=x)\pi(dx)$$
by some expression of the form $\int\limits_{S}\dots$ and then use CH-K equation.
My idea which I had was to have something like that
$$\int\limits_{S}P(X_1\in A|X_0=x)\pi(dx)=\int\limits_{S}P(X_2\in A|X_0=x)\pi(dx),$$
what is $$\pi(A)=\int\limits_{S}P(X_2\in A|X_0=x)\pi(dx)$$

And then I will continue. I will multiply both side with $\int\limits_S\dots$ and I will have $$\pi(A)=\int\limits_{S}P(X_3\in A|X_0=x)\pi(dx),$$
etc.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much for any idea.